# SQLEXCEPTION handler for wrong usage of stored procedures

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to handle errors like inexistence of stored procedure and wrong number of params?

As I see, the handler like bellow doesn’t catch such errors :(

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _tmp_proc(
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        IF IFNULL(@LOG_LEVEL, 1) < 2 THEN
            ROLLBACK;
        END IF;

        SELECT 'An error has occurred';
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    CALL inexisted_proc();
END
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to handle errors like inexistence of stored procedure
>   and wrong number of params?

Yes you can but it should be handled at the calling site and not in the procedure. With calling site, I mean your application end where you are calling the stored procedure. So if you are using `PHP` then use the error handling mechanism [`try .. catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) construct and in `catch` block either log the exception or perform as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However I'm looking for a way inside MySQL.